# увеличение картинки при нажатии в Swift3

Tags: xcode, swift, swift3

нужно чтоб при нажатии на картинку она увеличивалась по принципу приложения "вконтакте" 
есть вот такой код

```
let imgURL3 = NSURL(string: img3Array[indexPath.row])
    let imgURL2 = NSURL(string: img2Array[indexPath.row])
    let imgURL1 = NSURL(string: img1Array[indexPath.row])
    cell.img1.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    //cell.img1.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "animate"))
    //view.addSubview(cell.img1)
    //cell.img1.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "animate"))

    //cell.img2.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "animate"))
    //cell.img3.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "animate"))

    let w1 = cell.frame.width - 320 - 7
    let w2 = ((cell.frame.width - 320 - 7)/2)


    if imgURL3 == nil {
        cell.img3.image = nil
        if imgURL2 == nil {
            cell.img2.image = nil
            if imgURL1 == nil {
                cell.img1.image = nil
            }
            else {
                cell.img1.frame = CGRect(x: 13, y: 5, width: (300 + w1), height: 145)
                let imageView1 = cell.img1!
                imageView1.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: img1Array[indexPath.row]))
            }

        }
        else {
            cell.img1.frame = CGRect(x: 13, y: 5, width: (147 + w2), height: 145)
            cell.img2.frame = CGRect(x: (166 + w2), y: 5, width: (147 + w2), height: 145)
            let imageView1 = cell.img1!
            imageView1.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: img1Array[indexPath.row]))
            let imageView2 = cell.img2!
            imageView2.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: img2Array[indexPath.row]))
        }

    }
    else {
        cell.img1.frame = CGRect(x: 13, y: 5, width: (147 + w2), height: 145)
        cell.img2.frame = CGRect(x: (166 + w2), y: 5, width: (144 + w2), height: 71)
        cell.img3.frame = CGRect(x: (166 + w2), y: 79, width: (144 + w2), height: 71)

        let imageView1 = cell.img1!
        imageView1.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: img1Array[indexPath.row]))
        let imageView2 = cell.img2!
        imageView2.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: img2Array[indexPath.row]))
        let imageView3 = cell.img3!
        imageView3.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: img3Array[indexPath.row]))

    }
    print(timeArray)
    return cell


}
func animate() {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.75) {
        let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! TableViewCell
        let height = (cell.frame.width/200) * 100
        let y = self.tableView.frame.height / 2 - height / 2
        cell.img1.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: y, width: self.view.frame.width , height: height)
    }

}
```

без использования 
`cell.img1.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "animate"))` `view.addSubview(cell.img1)` 
все работает вот так

[image: без приближения]

но картинка не приближается.
 после добавления этого `cell.img1.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "animate"))` `view.addSubview(cell.img1)` .

```
func animate() {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.75) {
            let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! TableViewCell
            let height = (cell.frame.width/200) * 100
            let y = self.tableView.frame.height / 2 - height / 2
            cell.img1.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: y, width: self.view.frame.width , height: height)
        }

    }
```

все работает вот так 
[image: работает неверно] 
но зато приближает 
[image: приближение]

вопрос как сделать так чтоб картинки были на своих местах как на первом скрине и приближались как на третьем 
я думаю что проблема вот в этой строчке `view.addSubview(cell.img1)` но поменять ее у меня не получается пробовал типо вот так `cell.addSubview(cell.img1)` картинки становятся на места но не приближаются

Comment: Опишите подробнее что Вы имеете в виду.

Comment: @VAndrJ при нажатие на картинку она должна встать на центр экрана и немного увеличится, задний фон должен быть черный. При повторном нажатии все должно вернуться на свои места

Answer (score 1):

Вариант первый - при нажатии просто добавляйте программно `view` во весь экран с прозрачным фоном, на который добавляете необходимую картинку и все остальное (поделиться/еще чего, если конечно нужно). Либо изначально добавляете программно/через `storyboard` это `view` и скрываете его. При нажатии на ячейку показываете. При нажатии на view скрываете/удаляете его.

Вариант второй - при нажатии на ячейку переход на новый `UIViewController`, куда передаете необходимую информацию. При нажатии в любом месте закрываете его.

Comment: я думаю первый вариант мне подходит больше, у вас случайно нет никакой заготовки - примера?

Comment: если заюзать Hero, то второй вариант можно сделать не хуже чем в ВК

Comment: @АртемБалашов либо самому прописать transition animation. Декорации для второго варианта.