# как сделать чтоб tableview принимал размер дивайса

Tags: xcode, swift, swift3

[image: mainstoryboard]

[image: экран iphone 5s]

[image: экран iphone 6]

подскажите пожалуйста как сделать так чтоб при любом размере экрана все было на весь экран как в случае с 5s

```
if imgURL3 == nil {
    cell.img3.image = nil
    if imgURL2 == nil {
        cell.img2.image = nil
        if imgURL1 == nil {
            cell.img1.image = nil
        }
        else {
            cell.img1.frame = CGRect(x: 13, y: 5, width: 300, height: 145)
            let imageView1 = cell.img1!
            imageView1.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: img1Array[indexPath.row]))
        }

    }
    else {
        cell.img1.frame = CGRect(x: 13, y: 5, width: 147, height: 145)
        cell.img2.frame = CGRect(x: 166, y: 5, width: 147, height: 145)
        let imageView1 = cell.img1!
        imageView1.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: img1Array[indexPath.row]))
        let imageView2 = cell.img2!
        imageView2.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: img2Array[indexPath.row]))
    }

}
else {
    cell.img1.frame = CGRect(x: 13, y: 5, width: 147, height: 145)
    cell.img2.frame = CGRect(x: 166, y: 5, width: 144, height: 71)
    cell.img3.frame = CGRect(x: 166, y: 79, width: 144, height: 71)

    let imageView1 = cell.img1!
    imageView1.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: img1Array[indexPath.row]))
    let imageView2 = cell.img2!
    imageView2.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: img2Array[indexPath.row]))
    let imageView3 = cell.img3!
    imageView3.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: img3Array[indexPath.row]))

}
```

вот так у меня работают картинки

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Добавьте stack view's и constraint'sы.

Сначала выделите два лэйбла справа от Image View и выполните Editor > Embed In > Stack View. Затем тоже самое, только выделите Imave View и ваш получившийся Stack View. Теперь Ваш последний Stack View и лэйбл который под Image View.
Теперь разместите ваш финальный Stack View (который содержит все лэйблы и Image View) ближе к левому верхнему краю TableViewCell, там появятся голубые линии как на картинке, только в самой ячейке вашей таблицы.
 [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Теперь собственно сами constraints'ы. Тыкайте Resolve Auto Layout Issues и выбирайте для Selected View:  Resolve to suggested constraints.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а с картинками как это провернуть ведь их размер я прописываю в коде, а в мейнсториборд они 0 на 0 . @RedHairOnMyHead

Comment: я обновил картинку экрана iphone 6 теперь это выглядет вот так

Comment: Вычисляйте ширину ImageView в отношении к ширине view (или cell) на которой они лежат.

Comment: а как сделать чтоб она была разная то есть на четверке одна ширина на шестерке другая @RedHairOnMyHead

Comment: Я же говорю, через отношение к ширине экрана, т.е. если картинка допустим 100px, а ширина SE 240px и 6S 480px, то новое значение картинки в отношении к ширине экрана будет 200px. У вас ширина картинки просто должна рассчитываться по формуле (через отношение), а не задаваться фиксированно.
Другой вопрос, как вы сейчас рассчитываете размеры ваших картинок?

Comment: Ага, увидел ваш код. Сейчас посмотрю.

Comment: с этим можно что то придумать? @RedHairOnMyHead

Comment: Для случая с тремя картинками (двух и одно - аналогично):
W - ширина вашего cell или TableView
`let newWidth = Int((W - 13*2 - 6) / 2)`
`cell.img1.frame = CGRect(x: 13, y: 5, width: newWidth, height: 145) `
`cell.img2.frame = CGRect(x: newWidth + 6 + 13, y: 5, width: newWidth, height: 71) `
`cell.img3.frame = CGRect(x: newWidth + 6 + 13, y: 79, width: newWidth, height: 71)`
Но это пример ОЧЕНЬ плохого кода, т.к. вы рассчитываете все сами и пишите магические числа вроде: x: 13, y: 5! Почитайте лучше про constraints в коде (выше я вам показал как сделать их в Interfase Builder'е).

Comment: пожалуйста посмотрите вот этот вопрос если вас это не затруднит (https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/683630/%D1%83%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%B2-swift3)  @RedHairOnMyHead